# Android mediaserver process using processor / battery

Tags: android, media-player

I am building on my media player app, and am now in the alpha testing stage.  I have noticed that battery drain is increased while running my app.  When checking battery usage I see that the MediaServer process is the culprit.

I used OSMonitor to investigate and found mediaserver using 15-35%, with the following error message repeating constantly:

MP3Extractor(109)

Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.

Incidentally, the stock android player usage of this process is similar, and has the same error.  Should I write this off as expected result when using the SDK mediaplayer , or should I attempt to troubleshoot this error?

Any opinions are appreciated.

Thank You,
Josh McKinney

Answer (score 2):

I know there's an open issue with this one:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6765

In the thread they mention problems with corrupted media files on the SD card.

There are plenty of mentions of it on the web, a google search turns up plenty of hits on forums. Unfortunately, I haven't found a conclusive answer, but corrupted media files seems like a likely culprit.